# How to fill a structure when a pointer to it, is passed as an argument to a function

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have a function:

```
func (struct passwd* pw)
{

struct passwd* temp;
struct passwd* save;

temp = getpwnam("someuser");
/* since getpwnam returns a pointer to a static 
 * data buffer, I am copying the returned struct
 * to a local struct.
 */

if(temp) {
   save = malloc(sizeof *save);
   if (save) {
       memcpy(save, temp, sizeof(struct passwd));
       /* Here, I have to update passed pw* with this save struct. */
       *pw = *save; /* (~ memcpy) */
   }
}

}
```

The function which calls func(pw) is able to get the updated information.

But is it fine to use it as above. 
The statement *pw = *save is not a deep copy.
I do not want to copy each and every member of structure one by one like
pw->pw_shell = strdup(save->pw_shell) etc.

Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no shortcut to deep copy in C. You have to do it one by one.

Comment: @GajananH OK, what can be the side effects, If I use it as above. Thanks.

Comment: If you have pointers in your structure, memcopy will still copy only the pointer values and not the memory pointed to by the pointer. That means after memcopy if the source structure is freed 'completely' then  your destination will have dangling pointers.

Comment: Yes, This struct does have so many char* as members. :(
OK, I am not free-ing *save anywhere in the func(), so is it OK to use, If memleaks are compromised. My doubt is what happens to memory alloced to save, once func() call is completed and returned to parent.

Comment: It will just be leaked as there is no way to point to the memory allocated on the heap. The memory will be alive till the program ends. So if you are fine with memory leaks (which you should not be) then your code is fine.

Comment: hmm, there are so many leaks already :P I will see what can be done. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: WC. But resource leak is a big problem ! Use something like valgrind and fix all resource leaks. Surely it will help you in the long run !

Answer (score 1):

The function argument needs to be `struct passwd**`, and then change `*passwd`

Comment: I thought about it. But No, this is called in so many places, I do not want to change things everywhere.

Comment: You could make a macro (by an appropriate `#define func(X)` once in a header file) which does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a shallow copy if you like, but the result will only be good until the next call to getpenam.  But why copy twice?  Your malloc is a memory leak!  This will do just fine:

```
void func (struct passwd *pw)
{
  struct passwd *tmp = getpenam("someuser"); // get a pointer to a static struct
  *pw = *tmp;  // copy the struct to caller's storage.
}
```

If you want the deep copy, you have to do it field by field:

```
void deep_func (struct passwd *pw)
{
  struct passwd *tmp = getpenam("someuser"); // get a pointer to a static struct
  *pw = *tmp; // copy everything
  pw->pw_name = safe_strdup(pw->pw_name);  // Copy pointer contents.
  pw->pw_passwd = safe_strdup(pw->pw_passwd);
  // etc for all pointer fields
}
```

For the deep copy, you need a corresponding routine to free the malloc()'ed storage:

```
void free_passwd_fields(struct passwd *pw)
{
  free(pw->pw_name);
  free(pw->pw_passwd);
  // etc
}
```

A nice way to do the call is:

```
// Declare a 1-element array of structs.  
// No &'s are needed, so code is simplified, and a later change to malloc()/free() is very simple.
struct passwd pw[1];

// ... and later
func(pw);

// pw now behaves like a pointer to a struct, but with no malloc or free needed.
// For example:
printf("login name is %s\n", pw->pw_name);

// Done with copy.  Free it.
free_passwd_fields(pw);
```

Comment: Yes, the problem here is with getpwnam(). This system call always writes into same static data buffer. so further getpwnam() calls down the line will screw up pw structure too.

Comment: Yes, this works as stand alone. But I can not modify the existing huge code to look alike this. There are already so many functions which call the func(). Thanks for the suggestion.